# Typescript intellisens on html elements

Tags: html, typescript, intellisense

I would like to specify 3 types of images that are valid and also have support for the IDE so that it shows an error if the type entered is not valid

```
<image [src]="product.image" type="detail" [alt]="product.title" [title]="product.title"></image>
```

if the developer enters type="details" it should show an error

```
export interface ImageType {
  Detail: 'detail';
  Browes: 'browes';
  Thumbnail: 'thumbnail';
}

export interface ProductImage {
  url: string;
  type: ImageType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a union type of string literals, which you can later use for discriminated unions...

```
type ImageType = 'detail' | 'browes' | 'thumbnail';

export interface ProductImage {
  url: string;
  type: ImageType;
}
```

If I try to add a type that isn't listed... I get an error.

For example,

```
const image: ProductImage = {
  url: 'example.com',
  type: 'details'
}
```

Results in:

```
Type '{ url: string; type: "details"; }' is not assignable to type 'ProductImage'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type '"details"' is not assignable to type 'ImageType'.
```